# How to block url across a home Wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, internet, blocking

I am trying to block a list of urls across a home Wifi Network (like [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)) using open DNS. Since the router I am forced to use (Bell Home Hub 3000) has very limited options (it cannot block individual urls in the router settings) I thought something like open DNS would be a good option. However it does not block websites consistently across the network. That is, sometimes it works while sometimes it does not. I have followed all the steps in this [guide](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047135972-Getting-Started-Blocking-Allowing-Specific-Domains-with-Allow-Block-List) but I am still having problems.

**Is there a solution or another method that works network wide?**

If you need any clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Have you pointed the devices to the DNS you have created?, what devices are you having an issue with, do you have access to clear caches? are you routing port 53 traffic to another device (this should omit the need to configure devices...)

Comment: I am not sure what pointing is. I have just changed the DNS settings on the router (in now has open DNS set as the DNS). I have cleared DNS caches on all of the devices on the network. There seems to no pattern on when the sites are blocked and when they are not. I do not know what routing port 53 traffic means (I knowledge of networking is very limited).

Comment: Pointing = Change DNS settings on the devices connecting so that they know what the new DNS is. Changing the router DNS could have its flaws depending on the general setup, I am not overly familiar with open DNS. However DNS ruling generally works the same across the board, you should still have open DNS have an external DNS like google DNS for the pupose of translating addresses that are not known to the local DNS.

Comment: You can always get an Ethernet router and put it between your Bell router and network (and disable WIFI on the Bell router). I had no problems doing this with Ubiquity gear and ddwrt.  The trick is to have a rule that blocks/redirects DNS to non opendns servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would need to setup an external dns server and make it the default option on the router dhcp table. But it's possible it wouldn't work because of ipv6.

My suggestion would be to disable the router wireless interface and to setup a firewall+wifi between the router and your devices.

I guess I'd reccomend pfSense for beginners

Comment: Whilst what you say is partially correct, DNS & DHCP are essentially different entites, you can configure DNS further up the chain with no need to interfere with DHCP.